# Gradle jar published to Maven repo version name

Tags: gradle

I'm new to Gradle, and have inherited a project. We have a project that takes a .proto file and builds a `.java` file out of it, it then publishes the generated .jar it to a remote maven repo. The .proto generation is all working fine, but there are issues with the `.jar` versioning.

The publishing code in `build.gradle` is basically the same as [this example](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:complete_example) from the docs.

When I run `./gradlew clean build` it generates the `.jar` file under `build/libs`. the file name is `myname-1.1`. But when I pulled the file that was published to the maven repo it has the name `myname-1.1-20210xxx.065xxx-xx`. (x's for redaction). I can't find any details in the docs on this, but I assume when it publishes the `.jar` it appends the filename with a timestamp and possibly more.

I've been told they want the .jar file in the gradle project to have the same name as the one in the maven repo. Is this an unusual scenario? Is there a way to make these versions line up?

Comment: The code example you've linked doesn't match the behavior the least (that's why I've close-voted). Please provide debug information, because else this is all about guessing and not about knowing.

Answer (score 1):

Quite sure you are deploying a `SNAPSHOT` version to your repository.

This is the expected behavior. When you publish a `SNAPSHOT` version, a timestamp is appended at the end of file.